# Bubble sorting in Java is not working properly. It shows only 0

Tags: java, sorting

My code is not working properly. It is bubble sorting in Java. I know I can get any code from google but I think it is not good to me and google would not tell my why my code is not working.

Here is the code:

```
        int temp=0;
        int x=10;
        int [] array = new int [x];

        for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++){
            array[i]=i;
          //System.out.println(array[i]);
            if(array[i]>array[i+1]){
                temp=array[i+1];
                array[i+1]=array[i];
                array[i]=temp;
            }
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to sort an empty array. Add some numbers to `array`.

Comment: I've never seen a sorting algorithm that is O(n), you may be on to something here.. or missing an inner for loop. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/sorting1.html

Comment: Mhh in my opinion I am not trying to sort empty array because I give value of the for loop (i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're not populating your input `array` all of its values will be 0 - as such the resulting sorted array will contain all 0s

Additionally, you're overwriting your input `array` at

```
array[i]=i;
```

Which means you'll be modifying the array in a way that bubble sort does not do.

(I'm trying not to give the full answer as I assume you want to do get this working yourself)

Comment: There is an `array[i] = i` statement, but it's inside the loop, so I'm not sure what it does exactly (and don't feel like opening Eclipse to find out).